# When will my no fee transaction come back?

Tags: transactions, wallet

i've sent bitcoin with 0 fee 2 weeks ago.
but it doesn't come back.

i saw unconfirmed transactions coming back in 72 hours.

Is there a way to solve it other than double spend?

https://blockchain.info/ja/tx/0e846d7d4ea858cee2e6ba5915caffaa9628f60c120b4a5e6a493dc74f7ec58a

Comment: Which software did you use to send it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It generally "comes back" in a week or two. Actually the transaction gets discarded by the mining nodes from their memory pools. Until then, your transaction is stuck. 
However it depends on the wallet software as well if they let you spend it. 
I had complete control over the addresses I was using so it was easier for me to retrieve the funds.

Comment: I downvoted: when it is removed from mempools in general does not matter. The question is solely when your wallet software lets you respend it. This heavily depends on the software.